# Eken m009s Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I'm trying to produce an App for my Eken m009s Android, and want to know if there's some sample code in java out there that I can try, the ones that I've tried so far don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It won't work with the emulator in Eclipse that I created and the compiled files won't run in my Eken m009s.

Comment: What error do you get in the emulator?

Comment: Have you created an AVD?

Comment: yes I used the specs: target 2.2 API level 8, Res 800 x 460, SD support Yes, Abstract LCD Density: 240, MAX VM App Heap Size: 24, Touch Screen Support: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't know any more about getting it to work with Eclipse - maybe [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-857914.html) will help. You can also try using the [AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) to see if there is a problem loading that AVD.

Comment: The code I was using on the sample was for API version 12 I need sample code for API version 8 Thank you for your help though